# Oracle XE 11g the XE database was not found

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, windows-7-x64

I am a new one who started to use Oracle Database and faced the problem during installation the last verstion of `Oracle XE 11g` x64 to the Microsoft Windows 7 x64 Enterprise.

During installation were not any errors and Windows Services (`OracleXETNSListener` and `OracleServiceXE`) were successfully created and started. 
[image: Winservices screen]

However, when I try to get the list of available databases I receive an error

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[image: ORA-01034: ORACLE not available]

For some reason the **XE database was not created** into `%ORACLE_BASE%\oradata\XE`. 
[image]

The content of my listener.ora with localhost:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

I fixed tnsnames.ora by setting localhost IP address:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

sqlnet.ora contains both services:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE;NTS)
```

The log file from '%ORACLE_HOME%\server\log\myhost\client' contains this error:

> Oracle Database 11g Clusterware Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   Copyright 1996, 2010 Oracle. All rights reserved. 2016-01-20
>   19:51:43.920: [ default][5096]ut_read_reg:2:ocr registry key
>   SOFTWARE\Oracle\olr cannot be opened. error 2 [
>   CLSE][5096]clse_get_crs_home: Error retrieving OLR configuration [0]
>   [Error opening olr registry key. Не удается найти указанный файл. ]

How can I find what goes wrong and fix the problem?

Comment: First of all I should warn you that this will probably take a bit to trouble shoot!
Are you sure that the Database creation itself has been successful? The error you show indicates a problem with the client connecting to the Database. Can you share the content of **OracleDatabaseXEServerInstall.log**, it is located in the system root which usually is **C:\WINDOWS**

Comment: Unfortunately, did not find this log file into Windows and Oracle directories

Comment: Ok, but do you have a problem with installing the Database or with connecting to it? The location of your log file message would indicate that this is an issue with connecting to the Database.

Comment: An erorr is `ORA-01034: ORACLE not available`. I provided additional details about the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After struggling with this problem for almost a week I found a solution, how to make XE database available from this [source](http://mazdik.ru/?p=223). It is in Russian, I provide the solution right here in English.

1. Install the last version of Oracle XE 11gR2 from the Oracle site to the default location `c:\oraclexe` with default password **admin**. If not default, then you should edit scripts below (paths and pwd) before use them.
2. Run **cmd** command line under administrator privileges and use it until the end of reconfiguration. First of all, set environment variables for your DB:

   ```
   set ORACLE_SID=XE
   set ORACLE_BASE=c:\oraclexe\app\oracle 
   set ORACLE_HOME=c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
   ```
3. Delete the XE database by command:

   ```
   oradim -delete -sid XE
   ```
4. Delete `PWDXE.ORA file`:

   ```
   del %ORACLE_HOME%\database\PWDXE.ORA
   ```
5. Copy `init.ora` from `%ORACLE_HOME%\config\scripts` to `%ORACLE_HOME%\database`, instead of existing, rename it to `initXE.ora` and add the configuration below:

   ```
   open_cursors=300
   db_name=XE
   control_files=("C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\control.dbf")
   job_queue_processes=4
   compatible=11.2.0.0.0
   diagnostic_dest=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\.
   memory_target=1G
   sessions=100
   audit_file_dest=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\adump
   remote_login_passwordfile=EXCLUSIVE
   dispatchers="(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=XEXDB)"
   shared_servers=4
   undo_management=AUTO
   undo_tablespace=UNDOTBS1
   DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE = 10G
   DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\fast_recovery_area
   #optional
   nls_language="RUSSIAN"
   nls_territory="RUSSIA"
   ```
6. From the previous **cmd** line with admin previleges run the command to create Oracle services and file `%ORACLE_HOME%\database\PWDXE.ORA`:

   ```
   oradim -new -sid %ORACLE_SID% -intpwd admin -startmode auto -srvcstart system
   ```
7. Run commands below to stop Windows Oracle XE services, delete them and additional XE files:

   ```
   sqlplus /nolog
   connect sys/admin as sysdba;
   shutdown immediate;
   exit;
   del %ORACLE_BASE%\oradata\XE\CONTROL.DBF
   del %ORACLE_BASE%\fast_recovery_area\XE\ONLINELOG\*.LOG
   ```
8. Create two files into one directory:

#### createXE.cmd

```
set ORACLE_SID=XE
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
set ORACLE_BASE=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle
sqlplus /nolog @createXE.sql
```

#### createXE.sql

```sql
spool %ORACLE_BASE%\admin\XE\CreateXE.log;
connect sys/admin as sysdba;
startup nomount;
CREATE DATABASE XE
LOGFILE GROUP 1 SIZE 51200K,
GROUP 2 SIZE 51200K
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 1
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 100
CHARACTER SET CL8MSWIN1251
NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16
DATAFILE 'c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\system.dbf' SIZE 300M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10240K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
SYSAUX DATAFILE 'c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\sysaux.dbf' SIZE 120M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10240K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
SMALLFILE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE 'c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\temp.dbf' SIZE 20M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
SMALLFILE UNDO TABLESPACE UNDOTBS1 DATAFILE 'c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\undotbs1.dbf' SIZE 200M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5120K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
CREATE SMALLFILE TABLESPACE USERS DATAFILE 'c:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\users.dbf' SIZE 300M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  1280K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT  AUTO;
-- catalog
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catalog.sql;
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catblock.sql;
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catproc.sql;
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catoctk.sql;
connect system/manager
-- sqlplus profile
@%ORACLE_HOME%\sqlplus\admin\pupbld.sql;
@%ORACLE_HOME%\sqlplus\admin\help\hlpbld.sql helpus.sql;
connect sys/admin as sysdba;
-- xdb protocol
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catqm.sql change_on_install SYSAUX TEMP NO;
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catxdbj.sql;
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\catrul.sql;
-- compiling invalid objects
@%ORACLE_HOME%\rdbms\admin\utlrp.sql;
spool off;
exit;
```

9. Run **createdXE.cmd** from command line with admin privileges.
10. Done.