# Problems to Access XE database installed in Windows 7 x64. (Oracle 11g express)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My problem is the same as reported in this post:
[Oracle XE 11g the XE database was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907026/oracle-xe-11g-the-xe-database-was-not-found)

I tryed to execute the stepd indicated for Michael (the last answer in the post), but after the process i can't make a login in sqlplus anymore. Only appears:

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I don't change my password and I could log in before. I don't know what i do more.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: no, your problem is user/password - which USER are you trying to login as? and are you on the same machine as the database?

Comment: Same machine. The steps in other topic were to delete the Xe database and create another manually.
I don't make changes in user

Comment: you still haven't told us which user you're using. do below, or if you login as SYS dont' forget the AS SYSDBA in your connect string to sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

**You can login as a SYSDBA then change your password by doing this :**

1. Open SQL plus commandline
2. write " connect / as SYSDBA"
3. alter user "youruser" identified by  "newpassword";